# How to change Custom Fields to the right of the gutemberg editor

Tags: wordpress, custom-wordpress-pages, wordpress-gutenberg

I have a custom fields area that is at the end of the text editor. I would like to remove it and place it in a tab on the side of the editor. So I don’t need to scroll down to include a custom field.

Like this:
[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/ogo6O.jpg)

I have a custom fields area that is at the end of the text editor. I would like to remove it and place it in a tab on the side of the editor. So I don’t need to scroll down to include a custom field.

Like this:

How can I do this ?

I'm still a beginner in wordpres development. I don't know how to look for solutions like this. I've done several searches and found nothing. Any help and guidance will be greatly appreciated.